Can we reinstate the missing feed icons in CiviEvent?
As described in this question, the individual icons for the various feed types (including RSS) have gone from the 'Manage Events' page, replaced by a single icon and badly formatted description for 'iCalendar'.
Given that this change is not reflected in the documentation & doesn't appear to be addressed on github, perhaps its removal is a regression?

Looks like it was unintentional.  I've logged an issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5529
